# Replace all occurrences of a string in YAML

Tags: python

I have a YAML file. It contains values like `DATA_TO_FILL` and `NAME_TO_FILL`. I want to replace **all** occurrences of `DATA_TO_FILL` to be `DATA_FILLED` and `NAME_TO_FILL` to be `NAME_FILLED`. Two ways I thought of doing it:

1. Load the YAML file and iterate over the dict. But it's a nested dict so it will be quite complicated.
2. Convert the file input into a string, replace and convert back to YAML.

In BASH I would do:

```
sed -i 's/DATA_TO_FILL/DATA_FILLED/g' file.txt
```

What is the python way to do it?

Comment: There is more than way of doing this in Python, but check [replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace). Also please add the input, and your current code

Comment: @DaniMesejo I think I know how to do the second suggestion, but my question is what is the "right"/"cleanest"/"pythonic" way to do it.

Comment: Who is the moderator that closed the question?

Comment: From `str.replace()`, the next step was [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re).

Comment: `Who is the moderator that closed the question` [it doesn't take superpowers to suspend answering a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) until suspension is ended, most likely because it was improved enough. You should be privileged to [view and cast close and reopen votes on your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes).

Answer (score 1):

you can loop through the file and replace the occurrences:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input("file.txt", inplace=True):
    line.replace("DATA_TO_FILL", "DATA_FILLED"),
```